# ValueError: Expect x to be a 1-D sorted array_like.I am trying to plot smooth curve but couldn't

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I got two arrays after doing some calculation in python.

first one :

```
**t**: [0, 1.5e-13, 3e-13, 4.5e-13, 6e-13, 7.499999999999999e-13, 8.999999999999999e-13, 1.05e-12, 1.2e-12, 1.35e-12, 1.4999999999999999e-12, 1.6499999999999998e-12, 3e-13, 4.5e-13, 6e-13, 7.499999999999999e-13, 8.999999999999999e-13, 1.05e-12, 1.2e-12, 1.35e-12, 1.4999999999999999e-12]
```

second one:

```
**X2**: [2.0000000000000003e-34, 3.953299280814115e-14, -0.16661594736661114, 363384313676.0453, 1.6249307273647528e+24, -2.606395610181476e+37, 1.9393976227227167e+50, -1.0229289218046666e+63, 3.6974904635770745e+75, -3.685245806003695e+87, -7.685163462952308e+100, 8.267305810721622e+113, -0.16661594736661114, 363384313676.0453, 1.6249307273647528e+24, -2.606395610181476e+37, 1.9393976227227167e+50, -1.0229289218046666e+63, 3.6974904635770745e+75, -3.685245806003695e+87, -7.685163462952308e+100]
```

My code:

```
     from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
     from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline as sp, BSpline
     x_new = np.linspace(min(t), max(t), 300)
     spl = sp(t, X2, k=3)  
     a_BSpline = sp(t, X2)
     y_new = spl(x_new)

     plt.plot(x_new,y_new)
     plt.show()
```

I am getting error as

```
ValueError: Expect x to be a 1-D sorted array_like.
```

Answer (score 5):

So as the `ValueError` says, you need two expressions to be true: `1-D` and `sorted`. Which corresponds to:

```
if x.ndim != 1 or np.any(x[1:] <= x[:-1]):
         raise ValueError("Expect x to be a 1-D sorted array_like.")
```

If you check this:

```
t = np.array([0, 1.5e-13, 3e-13, 4.5e-13, 6e-13, 7.499999999999999e-13, 8.999999999999999e-13, 1.05e-12, 1.2e-12, 1.35e-12, 1.4999999999999999e-12, 1.6499999999999998e-12, 3e-13, 4.5e-13, 6e-13, 7.499999999999999e-13, 8.999999999999999e-13, 1.05e-12, 1.2e-12, 1.35e-12, 1.4999999999999999e-12])

print(t.ndim)
print(np.any(t[1:] <= t[:-1]))
```

The output will be:

```
1
True
```

Which means that your array is 1-D, but not sorted.

Your Problem is, that even if you sort your array by `np.sort()`, the error will still rise, because you got numbers in your array which are equal. Therefore the `<=` test will still be true.

I would suggest to `format()` your numbers so they become distinguishable.

Comment: i tried format(t), correct me if i am wrong(sorry, i am new to python)..now i got a new error :UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')  . Thank u for your help

Comment: You should format your numbers so they are different (and check it is not due to a data error) 
e.g. 1) add a small amount to them (enough to make them different, but not enough to affect accuracy)
OR 2) Delete duplicates
OR 3) Run separate interpolations for each different duplicate value and average the two different answers produced (extra work for questionable benefit)

I don't see how the format() function can be used here, I think it is a typo and should say 'format' not 'format()'?

Comment: In my case, it turned out that I had many sequences starting from low to high in a row in one long list. I had overseen that I needed an additional filter on each sequence.